# Pi/Infinite Numbers

Tags: pi

I'm curious about infinite numbers in computing, in particular pi.

For a computer to render a circle it would have to understand pi. But how can it if it is infinite?

Am I  looking too much into this? Would it just use a rounded value?

Comment: Actually, it wouldn't use the value of Pi to draw circles at all. The equation describing a circle is `x^2 + y^2 = R^2` - no mention of Pi, as you can see. For more details on how this is efficiently implemented, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm

Comment: By the way, pi isn't infinite. The proper word is "non-terminating" (I think).

Comment: The word you want is transcendental. Meditate on that.

Comment: Transcendental isn't what I meant - for example, the decimal value of 1/3 and the square root of 2 are both "infinite" (in the OP's usage), but neither is a transcendental number.

Comment: So my set of compasses understand Pi? and my string with a pencil at one end and a nail at the other understand Pi? Pi is just the ratio of the circumference of a circle to its diameter. You don't need to know anything about Pi to draw a circle.

Comment: I think the term you are looking for is an "irrational fraction" i.e. one that can't be represented exactly by a decimal number

Comment: I checked on MathWorld, and it wasn't clear about what the word I'm looking for is, but it's definitely not "irrational". Again, 1/3 is an "infinite" number but it's not irrational.

Comment: Buillding on what Pavel says, the only reason a computer would need to use Pi to render a circle is if you are trying to render a circle based on a given circumference.  Then the radius from a point would be in terms of pi.

Comment: Can we stop saying "infinite" please?

Comment: I don't think you need the word "fraction." What are the numerator and denominator of the fraction you're thinking about? And please don't say 22/7. :-)

Comment: It's called a "continued" number, decimal or fraction.

Comment: Transcendental is the best description here.

Comment: "Transcendental" is not the best word, because the issue referred to can happen even if  the subject number is not transcendental.  "Continued" is the technically correct for real numbers that have this problem in digital representation.

Comment: But if the subject number is representable by a fraction, you can often recast the code to use the numerator and denominator separately--something you can't do with PI without using an approximation, so it still seems like transcendental gets to the point the best.

Comment: There's no special term for numbers like `1/3`, because whether a number is "infinite" in that sense or not obviously depends on the base you use to express it. `1/3` is "infinite" in base-10 but not in base-3. And you don't usually deal with properties of number representation in particular base; you deal with the number itself; hence the lack of need to describe such things. On the other hand, irrational numbers such as sqrt(2) or Pi are "infinite" in any base.

Comment: However, for a better term, I'd nominate "terminating number".

Comment: I've heard 1/3 called a "continued fraction." Of course that depends on the base you are representing it in.

Comment: Pi is irrational. Transcendental yes, but irrational nonetheless.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong to say "continued fraction" above, as a continued fraction is something else altogether. I think that "continued decimal number" is the correct term.  I am not sure what the correct term is when applied to binary though.

Comment: Screw it, let's just go back to calling it infinite.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Mathematically, computers are both finite and non-continuous and therefore can neither know PI completely, nor correctly render a circle.

However, in the digital realm neither of these exist anyway, so it is sufficient to approximate PI and then use that to approximately render the circle, resulting in exactly the same pixels that would have been calculated from an exact PI anyway.

Either way, the resulting pixels aren't *really* a circle either, because they are a finite collection of digital points and a circle is a curve made up of an infinite number of points, most with irrational values.

(It has been pointed out to me that PI is not normally used to plot a circle, which is true, however, the methods used to plot a circle are related to the formulas used to express and/or calculate the value of PI, which still have the same issues).

Comment: I'd be curious to know why the random downvote is for?  If there's something wrong with my answer, please tell me.  But AFAIK, it is precisely correct, both mathematically and wrt computation theory.

Comment: Indeed, this is a perfectly good high-level explanation. What makes it so good is that it doesn't just apply to circles, but is effectively universal.

Comment: Actually, since humans are both non-discrete and "real" they are technically considered continuous.

Comment: It would be great to have a reference to a programming language resp. some additional details because the answer only covers the surface.

Answer (score 7):

An approximation is generally sufficient. To "render" a circle, the computer only needs to understand pi well enough to render accurately at whatever resolution (finite) is required.

Edit: as others have pointed out, you don't even need pi to render a circle. Still, the gist of the question was "how do computers deal with numbers like pi?" They use approximations, and whoever is using those approximations must decide whether they are precise enough for the given purpose.

Comment: To render a circle, you usually don't use pi at all.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need PI at all to draw a circle. There are many ways to draw a circle. The naive way is with sine and cosine.

The algorithm I saw most often on 8-bit machines was [Bresenham's circle](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article767.asp). You don't even need floating point math for that.

Comment: Sin() & Cos() are both typically calculated using PI, or with **e** or from tables of values that were themselves calculated using one or the other of these.  Yes, there are ways around it, but the most straight-forward methods do typically use PI.

Comment: Sine and cosine are related to e, pi, and imaginary numbers, but I disagree that it's _typical_ that they are calculated from any of those, or from tables representing those. I'd say it's typical for Sine and Cosine to be calculated by a series expansion that converges quickly. But the C language doesn't say how they should be calculated. You can find Taylor expansions that calculate the circular functions without any reference to pi or e. Although, as I said, all these entities are inter-related.

Comment: My apologies, you are correct Nosredna.  In my dotage, I seem to have forgotten how Taylor series, et al, are constructed.

Answer (score 2):

Computers just use a good approximation of pi.

From MSDN's article on [System.Math.PI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pi.aspx)

> The value of this field is
>   3.14159265358979323846.

BTW:  PI is NOT infinite.   It is irrational, meaning that it has an infinite number of non-repeating decimal places.  There are several expressions for PI that are very short. (see the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi) for more details)

Here is a wonderfully short expression for PI:

[image: PI as Integral]

Comment: PI does NOT have repeating decimal patterns as it is transcendental, which means that not only is it irrational (cannot be expressed as a fraction of two integers) it is also not algebraic (it isn't the solution to any rational polynomial equation).

Comment: Not repeating. It has an infinite number of *nonzero* decimal digits, but they don't repeat. (See the comments to the question for the debate about what this is actually called)

Comment: doh!  writing "repeating" was a total typo.  Fixed now as "non-repeating".

Answer (score 2):

Programming languages use a rounded constant for pi and similar "infinite" numbers.

In order to get higher precision you use iterative algorithms that are looped for as long as is required.

Comment: And this - not the drawing of circles - was the essence of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere I saw a proof that to draw a circle around the universe to millimetre accuracy, you'd need less than 100 digits of pi, in other words, far fewer digits than have been calculated by people with too much time on their hands (or too much computing power...). Now, if only I could find that proof... (edit) [found it](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/JavaScript/longnumAstronomical.htm)

Comment: Yeah, but what if you wanted to antialias it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it rounds it to a very small number, and is most likely a constant. If you use PHP, this is how PI renders:

```
echo pi(); // 3.1415926535898
echo M_PI; // 3.1415926535898
```

Just like you only need 3.14159 in High School,  computers only need so much to get it fairly accurate.

Comment: 17 decimal digits is about all you can represent.

Answer (score 1):

Computers just use rounded values of pi, unless of course there is a special case such as scientific computing. For example, in python pi is represented as:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.pi
3.1415926535897931
```

You can test this out for yourself in IDLE, pythons interactive interpreter.

Comment: Interesting:  C# reports the value as 3.14159265358979323846.
Note the digits: 97931 vs. 97932
That looks like something more than a rounding error to me.

Comment: Only about 17 of the digits are meaningful.  The last digit is little more than noise coming back from the platform's binary-to-decimal conversion algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

An approximation is often "good enough", whether you get it using a method from [this site](http://projectpi.sourceforge.net/) or [another one](http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Pi-by-Throwing-Frozen-Hot-Dogs).

"Rendering" is another matter.  When you have a finite screen resolution, a perfect value of π doesn't matter as much.

UPDATE: Calculation might be another matter, different from rendering.  Some applications might require greater precision than the standard double gives.  It depends on the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Pi is not infinite it is irrational, what mean that you can not express it as quotient. It has infinite number of digits. 
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_π_is_irrational](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational)

About computing find some informations here.
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_π](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_%CF%80)

Nice page is also this
http://3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592.com/